# Resultados de consulta a MySQL desde java

Tags: java

Buenas,

Realizando una consulta a base de datos desde java, soy incapaz de saber cómo interpretar los resultados. Tengo el siguiente código, que debería buscarme en una base de datos si el juego está incluido y si además la columna pertenece es igual a "-".

```
Statement st = comprueba.createStatement();
boolean isInsert;
    try (PreparedStatement ps = comprueba.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE Juego = ? AND Pertenece = ?")) {
     ps.setString(1, game);
     ps.setString(2, "-");              

     try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
         isInsert = !rs.next();
     }
}

if (!isInsert) { //si se cumple esta condicción significa que se cumplen las condiciones de juego base y que no pertenezca a ninguno
     resultado = "Si";
}
```

El caso es que no me está funcionando. Si me da algún resultado es porque el  ambas condiciones se cumplen, y entonces la variable `resultado` pasará a ser "Si". Pero algo tengo que estar haciendo mal. ¿Hay alguna forma similar de ver el resultado que me da de la consulta como `var_dump` en PHP?

Answer (score 2):

En JAVA para identificar si una query(consulta SQL) te retorna resultados debes utilizar el metodo execute() , el cual retorna un valor boolean true : si la query es un select y false en caso contrario :

```
boolean isSelect = comprueba.prepareCall("select * from tu_tabla").execute();
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de como debiese ser tu codigo :

```
boolean isSelect = comprueba.prepareCall("select * from tu_tabla").execute();
if(isSelect)
{
    //de ser verdadero isSelect debemos obtener los datos del Select con la clase ResultSet
    ResultSet resultados = comprueba.prepareCall("select * from tu_tabla").executeQuery();
    //debemos iterar sobre resultados hasta que la condicion pase a false(ya no habran mas filas por recorrer)
    while(resultados.next())
    {
        //obtenemos el String de la columna uno
        System.out.println(resultados.getString(1));
    }

}
else
{
    //en caso de que isSelect sea false, indica que la consulta SQL no es un Select , por lo tanto sera un INSERT,UPDATE O DELETE por lo que debemos validar que se hayan modificado las filas
    //el metodo executeUpdate() nos retornara un long indicando la cantidad de filas afectadas en caso de ser 0 ninguna fila fue modificada, de caso contrario nos indicara la cantidad de filas afectadas
    int filasModificadas = comprueba.prepareCall("select * from tu_tabla").executeUpdate();
}
```

Espero te sirva 
Saludos

Comment: Me podrian explicar por que votaron negativo ?